# INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR using custom shipping iOS PayPal SDK

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

### Details

I am currently facing an `INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR` when testing my Application via **PayPal** on **Sandbox** mode.

I am providing a custom shipping address to PayPal and using both of the shipping methods:

```
payPalConfig.payPalShippingAddressOption =  PayPalShippingAddressOption.Both
```

I create my shipping address with this code:

```
var payment = PayPalPayment()
payment.shippingAddress = PayPalShippingAddress(recipientName: "Some User", withLine1: "Address1", withLine2: "Address2", withCity: "London", withState: "United Kingdom", withPostalCode: "12321", withCountryCode: "GB")
```

### Issue

When I run application and make a Payment by choosing the address that **PayPal provided to me** **everything works OK**. But when I choose the **shipping address that I gave to PayPal**, **PayPal** throws this error:

> INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR - System error. Please try again later. (500) |
>   PayPal Debug-ID: xxxxxxxx [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.8.0]

This problems happens on the Web also as mentioned here: **[PayPal REST API does not take the customized shipping address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508080/paypal-rest-api-does-not-take-the-customized-shipping-address?rq=1)**

Is someone facing this error because of shipping?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on the PayPal sandbox backend. (As is the case any time HTTP 500 is returned)

Please reach out to [PayPal Merchant Technical Support](https://www.paypal.com/mts) and include the Debug Id that you've redacted in the error above. They can help look up the specific problem with that ID.